# While trying to load my jsp page I am getting the following HTTP Status 500 message

Tags: jsp

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Game.jsp(65,117) quote symbol expected
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:222)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:162)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:153)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseGetProperty(Parser.java:900)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1132)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1449)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:239)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.12 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
```

Below is the code of JSP file I am trying to run :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
button {
    align : center;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color:red;
}

.bombButton{

    align : center;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    background-color:red;

}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

    $(".bombButton").click(function(){
        $("button").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $(".bombButton").html("<b>B</b>");
    });

</script>
<jsp:useBean id="Mine" class = "MineBean" scope="session" ></jsp:useBean>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Mine Sweeper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type ="submit" ></button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <table style ="width:35% "  align = "center" >
        <% for( int i=0; i<10; i++) { %>
        <tr >
            <% for( int j=0; j<10; j++) { 
                Integer box_no = i*10+j;
                String id =null ;
                id = "i"+box_no.toString();
            %>
            <td >

                 <button id = <% out.print(id); %> type="button" class=<jsp:getProperty name="Mine" property="bombExists" param=<% out.print(box_no); %> />>
                 <%out.print(i*10+j); %></button><!---->
            </td>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the part that should point you to the cause of the problem:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Game.jsp(65,117) quote symbol expected
```

It tells you that in Game.jsp in line 65 and character 117 a quote is expected. So there might be a typo there.

**Update**
getProperty has only two attributes: name and property. The attribute param is only used with setProperty.

Comment: This is the line : Can you please suggest syntax error here :
 <button id = <% out.print(id); %> type="button" class=<jsp:getProperty name="Mine" property="bombExists" param=<% out.print(box_no); %> />